# Is there any way to dynamically add JSON fields in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

```
const demo = {
      data:[]
    };    
this.state.lossGroup.forEach(element => {
          const z= []
          this.state.selectedExposure.map((e) => {
            console.log(element,e.hazard_index.type )
            if (element == e.hazard_index.type) {
              z.push(e.id)
            }
          })
           demo.data.push({ element: z });
        });
```

I just want to store the array in json file with dynamic field name in element i.e. **element** should be the replaced with the value from the upper loop.

Comment: Which variable is your json? Can you share the value of your json?

Comment: I have edited json variable please check it.

Comment: Can you share some more information? What are you trying to do with the json file? Does `this.state.selectedExposure` contain information? Do you want to create json from the demo object?

Comment: Need more specific details about how results from code shown differ from expected

Comment: I have to deal with the "element"  from the **this.state.lossGroup.** The "element" values are like ['elem1','elem2','elem3']. And I want these value as field name in JSON file "demo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your key is dynamic they you can do this way.
`[element]` is way you can handle dynamic keys.

```
const demo = {
      data:[]
    };    
this.state.lossGroup.forEach(element => {
          const z= []
          this.state.selectedExposure.map((e) => {
            console.log(element,e.hazard_index.type )
            if (element == e.hazard_index.type) {
              z.push(e.id)
            }
          })
           demo.data.push({ [element] : z });
        });
```

[here](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-create-object-with-dynamic-keys) you can go through small blog which explains how you can set dynamic keys to json object.